# Difference between types of print statements in python

Tags: python

Why when I write in python `type(print)` it returns built-in function and when I write `type(print(“avc”))` it returns NoneType, shouldn’t it return str class because I thought that before printing to console python converts everything to str

Comment: Because the return value of the print function is None

Comment: Try `a = print("avc")` and then `print(a)`, in fact `a` will contain `None`

Answer (score 3):

If you try to get the type of `print`, you are forcing `type()` to return the type of the print keyword, which is a built-in function. But if you add parenthesis to print, you are executing the function and returning the type of the value that the function `returns`:

```
>>> type(print) #Type of print
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> type(print()) #Type of what print function RETURNS
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Wherever you add parenthesis to a function, you are executing it and getting a return value from it. *(Usually NoneType, unless the function returns some significant value)*